# Python discord.py не меняется громкость бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Всем привет, появилась проблема, при изменение громкости бота через $volume 50 к примеру, то она меняется, а при увеличении $volume 100 она не становится больше, бот музыку играет на youtube_dl, может из-за этого?

```py
@client.command()
async def volume(ctx, vol):
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    vol_new = int(vol)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        if 0 <= vol_new <= 100:
            voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(
                voice.source, vol_new / 100)
            print(voice.source.volume)
            await ctx.send(f"Громкость: {vol_new}")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Чё не понятного, значение громкости не меньше 0 и не больше 100")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Я не нахожусь в войс канале")
```

Answer (score 1):

Суть в том, что когда вы вводите комманду `$volume 50`, то громкось умножается на 0.5, т.е делится на 2.

Изначально громкость раняется 1.
В вашем случае, когда вы написали сначала `$volume 50`, она стала `1*0.5=0.5`, потом написали `$volume 100`, и она умножилась на 1(поскольку `100/100=1`), т.е не изменилась, а так и осталась 0.5.

Чтобы увеличить громкость в 2 раза в вашем случае нужно будет написать `$volume 200`.

Comment: не могли бы вы написать алгоритм (выражения), что бы при написании $volume 100 к примеру, громкость была 1, я зачту ответ, как лучший

Comment: Ещё я подумал, если так нельзя сделать, то получается выходит только писать сто строк? для каждой цифры свой случай